# Python primefac package not compiling on import

Tags: python, package, syntax-error, prime-factoring

I have successfully installed the python module primefac into the developer frameworks in my mac with El Capitan OS.  When I invoke "import primefac", it returns this error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/primefac.py", line 613
    print "\033[1;31m" + (names[g] if g in names else g) + "\033[;m"
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I highly doubt that my version of primefac.py has a syntax error, since I replaced the file various times with primefac.py from gitHub.

I am using Python 3.5.2 with primefac-1.1.  What could be the issue that causes my primefac.py to somehow be unreadable? Could it be in the wrong directory?

Answer (score 4):

The `primefac` library is only compatible with Python 2 currently -- if you want to use it, you'll need to use Python 2.7 :( You're using Python 3 which means the syntax in the library won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primefac) category section you'll see at this point of time primefac hasn't still being ported to python3.x. As an alternative I can suggest you can use [primefac-fork](https://github.com/elliptic-shiho/primefac-fork) which supports python3.x

Answer (score 0):

I am absolutely certain, that my function is no where near as optimized as their for python2, but mine works for python3.

The functions has no checker whether input is a positive integer larger than 1 or if it is anything else. You can add those in as you like. Actually I'll put an example in in a comment form.

It returns a dictionary where dict.keys are prime factors and dict.values are the exponent for respective prime factors

```py
def primeFactors(num):
  # try:
  #   if num != int(abs(num)) or num == 1:
  #     return {"WrongInputError": num}
  # except:
  #   return {"WrongInputError": num}
  prime_factors = dict()
  i = 2
  while num > 1:
    is_factor = False
    while num % i == 0:
      if not is_factor:
        prime_factors[i] = 1
      else:
        prime_factors[i] += 1
      is_factor = True
      num //= i
    i += 1
  return prime_factors
```